# Getting an array of string from an array of objects

Tags: c#, arrays

i have an array of Tag objects

```
class Tag
{
 public string Name;
 public string Parent;
}
```

i want code to return a list of the tag names as an array of strings

Comment: What ? Names of what , Name properties or Tag Instance Identifiers ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var names = from t in tags
            select t.Name;
```

Something like this will give you an IEnumerable over names, just use `.ToArray()` if you wan't array of those.

Comment: or simply 
tags.Select(t => t.Name);

Answer (score 6):

How about simply:

```
var tags = new List<Tag> {
  new Tag("1", "A"), 
  new Tag("2", "B"), 
  new Tag("3", "C"), 
};

List<string> names = tags.ConvertAll(t => t.Name);
```

No Linq needed, and if you need an array, call `ToArray()`.

Answer (score 0):

To best use `IEnumerable` interface. Otherwise you can use linq queries for that or basic foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

```
 return (from Tag in MyTagArray select Tag.Name).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] tagArray = (from t in tagList select t.Name).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want something like this :

```
public List<string> GetNamesOfTag(List<Tag> tags)
{
   List<string> Name = new List<string>();
   foreach(Tag item in tags)
   {
     Name.Add(item.name);
   }

   returns Name;
}
```

Comment: he said "as an array of strings"

Comment: @Charlie : Everyone wrote the code in LINQ, I wanted show something different.

Comment: @Aaron fair enough, good for C#2. You should edit your answer to return an array of strings rather than a list like the question says though.